# What is the idiomatic way of communicating between Onsen popover and its parent?

Tags: onsen-ui

This is [what I've got](http://codepen.io/gastlygem/pen/ZbpaPW) so far. First the script:

```js
ons.bootstrap();
.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = "Hello!";
  ons.createPopover('popover.html').then(function(popover) {
    $scope.popover = popover;
    popover.on('preshow', function() {
      popover._scope.greeting = $scope.greeting;
    });
    popover.on('posthide', function() {
      $scope.greeting = popover._scope.greeting;
      $scope.$apply();
    });
  });
});
```

And the page:

```
<ons-page ng-controller="AppController">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Popover</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <div style="margin-top: 100px; text-align: center">
    <ons-button modifier="light" ng-click="popover.show($event)">Show popover</ons-button>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top: 100px; text-align: center">{{greeting}}</div>

</ons-page>

<ons-template id="popover.html">
  <ons-popover direction="up down" cancelable>
    <div style="text-align: center; opacity: 0.8;">
      <input style="margin: 20px" type="text" ng-model="greeting" />
    </div>
  </ons-popover>
</ons-template>
```

This seems to work for me, but I'm not sure about the `popover._scope` part. Is it supposed to be accessed like that? I can't seem to find any other way.

So what is the idiomatic way to do this? And what are some good examples?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `parentScope` parameter to make the popover scope a descendant of the `AppController` scope:

```
module.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  ons.createPopover('popover.html', {parentScope: $scope});
});
```

Now you have some options on how to communicate between the scopes. Since the popover scope is a descendant of the `AppController` scope you can for instance use `$scope.$emit()` to emit events when the value changes:

```
module.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hello!';

  ons.createPopover('popover.html', {parentScope: $scope}).then(function(popover) {
    $scope.popover = popover;
  });

  $scope.$on('update', function(event, value) {
    $scope.greeting = value;
  });
})

.controller('PopoverController', function($scope) {
  $scope.$watch('greeting', function(value) {
    $scope.$emit('update', value);
  });
});
```

I made a simple example:
http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/avmqOP

You can also use `ngModel` to access the the value but keep in mind that it's actually the grandparent so in that case you need to do `ng-model="$parent.$parent.greeting"` which is not very nice.

I would recommend the event approach.

Comment: The answer is enlightening, but slightly differs with what I want: What if I want the value to be updated on the popover hide event?